How can I write a Spyder IDE Datafame to and MS Access Database Table
I am trying to write from Spyder IDE Dataframe to MS Access table.  I am using dummy data from a statement in the Python code where it works great!  The goal is reading the excel file to Spyder IDE that works and does nothing yet.  Just do not know how to manipulate from the Spyder IDE Dataframen to MS Access table.
xlsx_path = (r'F:\Kevin\CPD_Night\ALC_2022068_06282024.xlsx')
df_ALC = pd.read_excel(xlsx_path)
df_dateofnotice = df_ALC['dateofnotice']
df_provnbr = df_ALC['provnbr']


print(df_dateofnotice )
print(df_provnbr )

sql="Insert into tblALC_tempdata (dateofnotice, provnbr) values ('07/16/2024', '9999')"
print('after sql statement next connect to MS Access')


conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; 
DBQ=F:\Kevin\CPD_Night\ALC_Testing.accdb;')

cur = conn.cursor() 

cur.execute(sql)

conn.commit() 


cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tblALC_tempdata' )
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)

[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/A2sY1Zr8.png)
enter image description here
I would like the Sypder Dataframe data transferred to the MS Access Database table.enter image description here

Does your insert statement work as intended?

You should store dates and numbers as Date and Long, not text.

As per SQL FIXED statement all works.  The reason of help is how to manipulate python to grab the data ( 2 columns) from the dataframe and insert into MS Access table.  Any suggestions
